# JSON: is this a json array?

Tags: arrays, json

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

I know that this is a json array.
I want to do something like this:

```
"employees":[
    "manager":{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    "boss1":{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    "boss2":{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

Is this json format? Is this a json array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add some  { and  } you can make it valid jsons, like this:

```
{"employees":[
    {"manager":{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}}, 
    {"boss1":{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}}, 
    {"boss2":{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}} 
]}
```

I tested it on https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and this is valid. Without the need to add the extra "position".

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not JSON array, you can check it on this link https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ just past your code on the left side, and surround it with {} , and you will see where the problem is. Also you can test JSON there in the future.

My suggestion is to use something like this.

```
"employees":[
    {"position":"manager", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"position":"boss1", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"position":"boss2", "firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

This would be valid JSON array.